# What does exactly do the command "REM INSERTING into TABLE_NAME" in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some SQL scripts for Oracle and I wonder to know exactly what is the objective of the following line:

**`REM INSERTING into TABLE_NAME`**

After this line I get the inserts for the table.

```
Insert into TABLE_NAME (ID,ENUM_KEY,NAME,DESCRIPTION) values (3,3,'T_EXIT_POINT','T_EXIT_POINT');
Insert into TABLE_NAME (ID,ENUM_KEY,NAME,DESCRIPTION) values (4,4,'T_CONDITION','T_CONDITION');
```

Anyone can explain me this `REM INSERTING`, or where to find documentation about it?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

REM, or short for REMARK, is used in SQL*Plus to indicate the beginning of a comment in a SQL script. Read more about REM in the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve034.htm#SQPUG054).

Instead of

```
 REM INSERTING into TABLE_NAME
```

I suggest you use PROMPT

```
 PROMPT INSERTING into TABLE_NAME
```

That way the script output would contain the string "INSERTING into TABLE_NAME".

More about PROMPT [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve032.htm#SQPUG052). It's especially useful when you have ECHO OFF.

Answer (score 25):

I believe REM is a comment, short for "REMARK".  Everything after REM is ignored by the Oracle parser.

I would remove such a thing if I saw it.  It adds no new information; it's little more than visual clutter.  These kinds of comments should be discouraged.

Comment: I have seen good, useful comments. They are way too freakin' *rare*... most are screamingly obvious wastes of bitbucket space, lol - but a good, useful, well written comment as in-place documentation can be a beautiful thing to the guy trying to maintain something less than obvious, a few years later, after the person who wrote it is gone. Less-than-obvious is also less than ideal, but sometimes the real solution - fixing the upstream mess - isn't an option. :(

Answer (score 8):

REM is just a way to provide comments in the script file as we have "/* */", "#", etc in other programming languages. Whatever is followed by "REM" in that particular line is ignored by the compiler.